String folder structure with all matching folders listed
I've been trying to do this for a few days and really I'm struggling. How do I generate all possible scanned folders from the string below and replace all possible folders in %%%ANY_DIR%%%?
$multiple_folder_scan_structure = "Customers/%%%ANY_DIR%%%/HW/%%%ANY_DIR%%%/XR7 and XR7 plus (7702 and 7703)";
The expected output should list all possible complete folder paths found within the defined structure above. With one %%%ANY_DIR%%% this is easy, but with 2 or 3, I'm completely lost as to how to accomplish this.
An example of the expected array would like something like this:
../../Customers/Morrisons/HW/SS90 Card Only (7709)/XR7 and XR7 plus (7702 and 7703)
../../Customers/Morrisons/HW/Test/XR7 and XR7 plus (7702 and 7703)
../../Customers/Sainsbury's/HW/SS90 Card Only (7709)/XR7 and XR7 plus (7702 and 7703)
../../Customers/Tesco/HW/SS90 Card Only (7709)/XR7 and XR7 plus (7702 and 7703)

I have tried to below among other codes, but it clashes as soon as I scan the first %%%ANY_DIR%%%, then the variable I use suddenly isn't linear. I feel I should implement a dynamic loop (maybe While), but I'm clueless.
I use my "scan_dir_sorted" function here that scans any folder and puts it into an array.
      $multiple_folder_scan_structure_anydir_exp = explode('/', $multiple_folder_scan_structure);
      
      $any_dir_counter = 0;
      foreach ($multiple_folder_scan_structure_anydir_exp as $folder)  {
        if (strtoupper($folder) == "%%%ANY_DIR%%%")  {
          //echo $multiple_folder . "<br>";
          
            foreach (scan_dir_sorted($multiple_folder) as $any_dir)  {
              //echo $multiple_folder . $any_dir . "<br>";
              $any_dir_scanned_folders[$any_dir_counter][] = $any_dir;
            
            }
          $any_dir_counter++;
          $multiple_folder .= $folder . "/";
        }
        else
          $multiple_folder .= $folder . "/";
      }

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

What about function glob()? Does it not match your needs?

Thanks Michal, you nailed on the head, indeed the answer was the Glob function.
For anyone looking for the same answer, the function worked for me like this:
glob("../../Customers/*/HW/*/XR7 and XR7 plus (7702 and 7703)");

I can't believe I didn't find this function earlier.
